# How can I calculate avg of data from django form and store in variable for later use?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In the readerpage function, in my views.py, I am trying to calculate the avg of the two variables: `readability_rating` and `actionability_rating`, and store the result in `avg_rating`

```
def readerpage(request, content_id):
    content = get_object_or_404(Content, pk=content_id)
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        review = form.save(commit=False)
        review.content = content
        readability_rating = form.cleaned_data['readability_rating']
        readability = form.cleaned_data['readability']
        actionability_rating = form.cleaned_data['actionability_rating']
        actionability = form.cleaned_data['actionability']
        general_comments = form.cleaned_data['general_comments']
        review.avg_rating = (float(readability_rating) +
                             float(actionability_rating)) / 2
        review.save()
        return redirect('home')
    args = {'content': content, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'content/readerpage.html', args)
```

The problem is that with this setup the two variables are still ChoiceFields - as such the above setup gives me the error:

> float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ChoiceField'

I’ve tried converting them to floats without any luck.
I also attempted using the TypedChoiceField with `coerce=float`, still with no luck

I’m not sure whether the best place to calculate this is in my function, my form, or my model?

**models.py**:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    readability = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=500)
    readability_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    actionability = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=500)
    actionability_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    general_comments = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=500)
    avg_rating = models.FloatField(null=True)


    def _str_(self):
        return self.title
```

**forms.py**:

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    readability = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    readability_rating = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)])
    actionability = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    actionability_rating = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)])
    general_comments = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)


    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['readability', 'readability_rating',
                  'actionability', 'actionability_rating', 'general_comments']
```

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables are ChoiceFields because you are declaring them as ChoiceFields in view function. Shouldn't you just fetch the values from your cleaned_data?

```
readability_rating = form.cleaned_data['readability_rating']
```

And to the second part of your question: Why not add it as a @property to your model?

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Made it work by fetching it from the cleaned data. To be honest I thought the form and the view function that utilises the form should be identical.

Comment: Was a pleasure! If the solution works for you maybe you could mark it as accepted anserwer?